# CSS bold font antialiased

Tags: css, fonts, webkit

I'm facing in issue with a bold font on Safari.
The problem only occures if you are using Windows + Safari.

I got a bold text which breaks pretty ugly because in WebKit browser
Is there anyway to change the font-size only for WebKit browser;

- without creating a new safari related stylesheet
- without changing the font for other browsers

Following trick does not work, because it is Safari used on Windows.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Any idea how to change the `fontSize` / `fontWeight` for Windows Safari only?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to change it for WebKit or Safari?

Comment: need to change it in safari browser 5.1.7

Comment: are you using a google web font? If so, don't use font-weight: bold; on a regular weight font to make it bold. You need to use font-style: 700; or whatever the weight number value is. Please post a fiddle with your code for more help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could link a separate CSS page if it is Safari, by using PHP.

```
<?php
$browser= get_browser();
if($browser->browser == 'Safari') {
    echo '<link href="SafariCSSPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
} 
?>
```